# Why did the Elvish Rings of Power lose their power?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, elves, sauron, tolkiens-legendarium

The [wiki for Nenya says](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Nenya) of the 3 elvish rings,

> Their existence was hidden from Sauron, so they were untouched by his evil.

[It also says](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Three_Rings#The_Three),

> After the destruction of the One Ring and the defeat of Sauron, [Nenya's] power faded along with the other Rings of Power.

The first quote states that they *are not* connected. The second states that they *are* connected. If the 3 rings were distinct and untainted by Sauron and his ring, why would their power fade after the destruction of the One Ring?

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say that the existence of the Three was "hidden" from Sauron; he knew that they *existed*, he just didn't know where they were sent after he destroyed Eregion. The LotR Wikia doesn't always have the clearest wording

Comment: Thanks. They key part of that phrase, I think, is the `untouched` statement. Is that also inaccurate or incomplete in the wiki's account?

Comment: duplicate or not, the [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68351/38299) in that question answers this one

Comment: @Jeff Sort of. The Three are "untouched" in the sense that Sauron wasn't directly involved in their creation (whereas he personally helped create the Seven and the Nine), but they were still created using Sauron's techniques

Comment: I suppose there is enough overlap between these two questions. I am not quite satisfied with the "Sauron wasn't in the room" explanation. I don't think it is consequential if he physically touched the rings or not. The implication of that sentence, in my mind, is that the rings have not been corrupted or dominated by him - which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Jeff - the distinction is that while they weren't corrupted by him, they *were* under his domination, because Celebrimbor and the other Elves used knowledge gained from him in their making.  This isn't a binary either/or, it's somewhere in between the two extremes.

Comment: Because Sauron wasn't involved in the making of the Three, they didn't have the ill effects on their wearers that the others did; but they were made using the same principles; their "power source", if you like, was the same (cf "Sauron made One Ring to rule all the others, and their power was bound up with it"). Thus when it was destroyed, they lost their power.

Comment: Thanks all! And sorry for the dupe. It wasn't showing up in the search results before I posted.

Comment: @Jeff It's a bit of an oversimplification, but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKU0qDpu3AM&feature=youtu.be&t=22s) has a pretty good high-level overview if you're still confused

Comment: @JasonBaker Thanks. I really like that video... but actually, it is what got me confused in the first place. I went looking in the wiki to confirm or deny what was said there. I thought that the wiki made a better, more quotable source for this question than the video.

Comment: @Jeff Oh well, worth a shot. Now you know that we're a much better resource than the Wikia